# vbs file drag and drop a folder

Tags: file, vbscript, drag

I need to make a vbs file that asks for the minimum file size when you drag and drop a folder to it. It's a little wierd. But then, it should return the input as a string that will be turned into an integer. Then it should look for files that are bigger than this minimum file size(all, i guess) and list their folder(if it's in a sub-folder), name and size.

I found some stuff on the internet but I'm a bit lost

```
Option Explicit
Dim FolderPath, objFSO, objFolder, objFile, input, objArgs

input = InputBox("Minimum size: ")

Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For i = 0 to objArgs.count
    on error resume next

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objArgs(i))

    If err.number <> 0 then
        ProcessFile(objArgs(i))
    Else
        For Each file In folder.Files
            ProcessFile(file.path)
        Next
    End if
    On Error Goto 0
Next

Function ProcessFile(sFilePath)
    msgbox "Now processing file: " & sFilePath

For each objFile in objFolder.Files
    WScript.Echo objFile.Name, objFile.Size & "bytes" & VbCR_
        & "created: " & objFile.DateCreated & VbCR_
        & "modified: " & objFile.DateLastModified
Next
```

Comment: Theree is no end function statement at the end of your function ProcessFiles.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some issues in your code. You're using `folder.files` but you don't have `folder` declared (or defined) anywhere. The only reason you're not getting an error is because you have `On Error Resume Next` specified. There's no need to use `On Error` here and it should be removed so that you can properly debug your script. Here's a starting point for you.

```
' Get the folder dropped onto our script...
strFolder = WScript.Arguments(0)

' Ask for minimum file size...
intMinSize = InputBox("Minimum size: ")

' Recursively check each file with the folder and its subfolders...
DoFolder strFolder

Sub DoFolder(strFolder)

    ' Check each file...
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder).Files
        If objFile.Size >= intMinSize Then
            WScript.Echo "Path: " & objFile.Path & vbCrLf & "Size: " & objFile.Size
        End If
    Next

    ' Recursively check each subfolder...
    For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder).SubFolders
        DoFolder objFolder.Path
    Next

End Sub
```

This isn't a complete script. Notice I haven't declared `objFSO` anywhere. I haven't checked that `strFolder` is a valid folder or that `intMinSize` is actually a number. I'll leave it up to you to fill in the missing pieces. But this should get you going.